# c# excel addin: how to get when a file is opened

Tags: c#, excel, events, add-in

my purpose is to create and install an Excel add-in in order to perform some checks on Excel files when they are opened. I wrote the following code:

```
private void InternalStartup()
{
this.Application.WorkbookOpen += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(Application_WorkbookOpenHandle);
this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
}
void Application_WorkbookOpenHandle(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("WORKBOOK OPENED");
// perform checks and then exit
}
```

I have succesfully published and installed the add-in.

However:

I can see the message if I open directly an Excel file.

I can see the message if I open Excel and then I open a file.

I can't see the message if I only open Excel.

I can't see the message if I open Excel and I click on "new".

I can't see the message if I open a file from command: Excel.exe c:\temp\book1.xls

I need the message to be displayed in all these situations.
What event can I handle?

ps. I know I could try to reach my goal with a Windows service, but I stritcly have to use an Excel add-in.

Comment: The WorkbookOpen event is fired when Excel open a workbook (actually a file). You may use your message box code in Startup event also to detect Excel start (actually your plugin start).

Comment: What is the Startup event? I can't find it. Also, if the add-in is loaded after Excel starts, how can I handle an event raised before its load?

Comment: minor note: are you sure this is not a workbook add-in but an application add-in? Your app add-in should get loaded with the Excel app starting if you use the `private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` in your `ThisAddIn.cs` and this is where you handle start up from

Comment: The startup event is the one you use in your code sample : this.Startup += ...

Comment: Ok, if I place a messagebox in the 'ThisAddIn_Startup' I can see the message in almost all the cases, except when I have Excel opened and I click on "New" to get a new blank file. So my add-in seems related to the workbook and not to the application. But if I open Excel (only the program, with no workbook opened) in the add-in list I can find mine installed and activated....

Comment: @maurice85 it's because you are not opening another Instance of Excel. Your add-in is already loaded in the current instance and when you click NEW - WORKBOOK you are still in the same instance so your addin is already loaded and you wont see the msgbox. all your doing in that case is starting a new workbook within the current instance. hope this helps